# Import CheckBox Settings From Excel

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have an Excel worksheet that has 14 entries with checkboxes in it. I'd like to read the state of those checkboxes into a corresponding checkbox in Visual Basic. I'm struggling with this access, however. I believe I can only access the checkboxes in the Excel sheet by name, as I don't think they have an index like the Visual Basic checkbox does, so I think I have to check all 14 individually. So two questions:

1) Is it true I have to reference the Excel checkbox by name, as they're not associated with a specific index, correct (which also means 14 individual lines for access, rather than some sort of for loop)?

2) How do I actually read the value of the checkboxes into my Vsual Basic program? I have tried this:

```
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    oExcel = New Excel.Application      'Create a new instance of Excel
    oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\QA Controller Test Files\" & SelectController.Text & ".xlsm")
    oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)

    Dim checked As Boolean = oSheet.Shapes("Verify USB Revision Reporting").ControlFormat.Value
        If checked Then TestSelection.CheckedItems(1) = True
```

I get an error message that says "Interface 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shapes' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop through all the shapes on the worksheet and test each one to make sure you have a checkbox. Here is an example (I don't have Visual Basic on my workstation here, but this should work):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetCheckBoxes()
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oShape As Shape

    Set oSheet = ActiveSheet

    For Each oShape In oSheet.Shapes
        If (oShape.Type = msoFormControl) And (oShape.FormControlType = xlCheckBox) Then
            If oShape.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
                Debug.Print "box '" & oShape.Name & "' is checked!"
            Else
                Debug.Print "box '" & oShape.Name & "' is not checked!"
            End If
        End If
    Next oShape
End Sub
```

Comment: With a slight bit of tweaking, this is *almost* working perfectly. Only issue I have is that it keeps finding one extra shape, and I can't tell what it think's it's seeing. My Excel sheet does have a few other cells, but only 14 entries are checkboxes. But it keeps finding 15. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, disregard, I found out how to show all Shapes from the Selection Pain menu in Excel and I do indeed have an extra shape.